# Handle names with spaces when iterating recursively over files

Tags: bash, find, filenames, recursive

I am trying to recursively convert all `.mkv` files in a folder structure with subfolders to `.mp4`.

I got a standard line that works in just the present folder

```
for video in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$video" -acodec aac -ac 2 "${video%.*}".mp4; rm "$video"; done
```

So I thought I would make something like

```
for video in $(find . -name *.mp4); do ffmpeg -i "$video" -acodec aac -ac 2 "${video%.*}".mkv; rm "$video"; done
```

But this seems to fail on folders with spaces in them. Can anyone point out my error?

Comment: Check out [BashFAQ #20: "How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) Note that `ffmpeg` consumes its input, so you need to work around that (see [BashFAQ #89: "I'm reading a file line by line and running ssh or ffmpeg, only the first line gets processed!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089)).

Comment: Exactly the [Bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your error lies in using `find` in a command substitution. A command substitution always results in a single string. If you leave the substitution unquoted, that string will undergo splitting on spaces, tabs and newlines (by default). The split-up words will be processed for filename globbing.  The resulting strings are what your loop will iterate over, which is not what you want.

Your loop that works for the current directory (fixing the issue with filenames starting with a dash):

```bsh
for video in ./*.mkv; do
    ffmpeg -i "$video" -acodec aac -ac 2 "${video%.*}".mp4
    rm "$video"
done
```

Changed to work recursively, by enabling the `**` globbing pattern (and using `nullglob` to avoid running the loop at all if there are no matches):

```bsh
shopt -s globstar nullglob

for video in ./**/*.mkv; do
    ffmpeg -i "$video" -acodec aac -ac 2 "${video%.*}".mp4
    rm "$video"
done
```

The two loops above would not care about the filetype and would happily feed `ffmpeg` with symbolic links, directories, or any other non-regular type of file, as long as the name matched the given pattern.

Alternatively, delegating the recursive generation of pathnames to `find` (also only selecting regular files):

```bsh
find . -name '*.mkv' -type f -exec sh -c '
    for video do
        ffmpeg -i "$video" -acodec aac -ac 2 "${video%.*}".mp4
        rm "$video"
    done' sh {} +
```

The above would also find hidden names matching the pattern, which the first two shell loops would not do (unless you enable the `dotglob` shell option).

Other relevant questions:

- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)
- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)